# Rerunning a prediction on the whole dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recommendation-engine

I want to predict the `Decision` based on the following dataset:

```
     userId        itemId      Decision
  0      u1            i1             0
  1      u1            i2             1
  2      u2            i1             1
  3      u2            i3             0
  4      u2            i4             1
  5      u3            i5             0
    ...
```

I did the following and I am happy with the result:

```
import numpy as np
from surprise import KNNWithMeans, Dataset, Reader
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split

reader = Reader(rating_scale=(0, 1))
data = Dataset.load_from_df(df_2[['userId', 'itenId', 'Decision']], reader)
trainset, testset = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.25)
algo = KNNWithMeans()
algo.fit(trainset)
test = algo.test(testset)
test = pd.DataFrame(test)
test.drop("details", inplace=True, axis=1)
test.columns = ['userId', 'itemId', 'actual', 'cf_predictions']
```

So `test` looks something like this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'userId': ['u3', 'u3', 'u4', 'u4', 'u5', 'u5'],
                     'itemId': ['i5', 'i6', 'i1', 'i3', 'i4', 'i5'],
                     'actual': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                     'cf_predictions': [0.05, 0.66, 0.99, 0.04, 0.98, 0.06]})
```

I even rounded them up!

```
def g(row):
    if row['cf_predictions'] > 0.5:
        val = 1.0
    else:
        val = 0.0
    return val

test['cf_threshold'] = test.apply(g, axis=1)
```

But I want to rerun the model on the whole dataset, not just on the `testset`. Do I "concatenate" the `trainset` and `testset`? If I type `trainset` it gives me `<surprise.trainset.Trainset at 0x1593f42c550>`

Answer (score 0):

you can predict all the data by using

```
prediction_data = data.drop('Decision', axis=1)  
preds = algo.predict(prediction_data)
```

Comment: Stupid question, but do you mean dropping the `Decision` column from the original dataframe (named `df_2` in my code) or from `data` as defined in my code above? Because `data` is not a dataframe, is it?

Comment: There is no stupid question my friend.  But yes data is a dataframe you can check the documentation  https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dataset.html  but i didn't use inplace = True that means i make a copy of data without Decision column.

Comment: If I drop it from the dataframe, I get `TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iid'`. If I drop it from the `data`, I get `AttributeError: 'DatasetAutoFolds' object has no attribute 'drop'`. It's just that this library works a bit differently compared to normal classification models...

Comment: Seriously i didn't find a function that can help you.  but i find a solution not professional `train_test_split(data, test_size=0.99)`   with a test size of 0.99 %.But i didn't know a solution for this problem. you test this function https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise/issues/193 and this link https://github.com/Microsoft/Recommenders/blob/60f246051904170dac0816d44f90739f487fc079/reco_utils/recommender/surprise/surprise_utils.py#L8

Comment: @sknon7 Thank you, that's actually not a bad idea haha. But then what will it be trained on? What I am trying to do right now is to convert my dataframe `df_2` to a list of tuples, just like my `testset` is represented as. But it's huge and I don't even have enough memory haha.

Comment: For the first part of the question you can do `trainset1, testset1 = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.25)` for training your model next you `trainset2, testset2 = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.99)` but for the second part, when i have a huge dataset i use Dask or Spark. I hope that i helped you a little.